# Canonical sheaf of the fiber of a flat morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, short-exact-sequences

This is probably a trivial question.

While reading the paper

R. Elkik, Singularites rationnelles et deformations, *Invent. Math.* 47 Ž1978., 139147.

I came across the following short exact sequence. Consider a flat morphism $f:X\rightarrow S=Spec(R)$ of k-schemes of finite type, $X$ normal + CM, and pick a regular parameter $t\in R$. If $X_t=X\times_{S} Spec R/tR$ is the fiber over $t$, then multiplication by $t$ induces a short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \omega_X \stackrel{t}{\rightarrow} \omega_X \rightarrow \omega_{X_t} \rightarrow 0$$

Is it straightforward to derive such a sequence?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Note first that we have a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to O_X \xrightarrow{t} O_X \to O_{X_t} \to 0
$$
If $D$ is the divisor corresponding to $t = 0$ on $X$, you can also view this as 
$$0 \to O_X(-D) \to O_X \to O_D \to 0.$$

Anyways, now apply the functor $\mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(\bullet, \omega_X)$.  You get
$$
0 \to \mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(O_{X,t}, \omega_{X}) \to \mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(O_X, \omega_X) \xrightarrow{t} \mathcal{H}om_{O_X}(O_X, \omega_X) \to \mathcal{E}xt^1(O_{X_t}, \omega_X) \to \mathcal{E}xt^1_{O_X}(O_X, \omega_X)
$$
Ok, the first term is zero (homing torsion into non-torsion), the last term is also zero since you are homing from a free module.  Finally, $\mathcal{E}xt^1(O_{X_t}, \omega_X) = \omega_{X_t}$ by basic properties of dualizing/canonical modules, and the result follows.

Comment: I suppose $\omega_X$ really means $\omega_{X/R}$ (not the same thing if $R$ isn't Gorenstein.) The fact that $\omega_X$ is $R$-flat rests on the fact that $f$ automatically has CM fibers (since it is flat and $X$ is CM). Once this $R$-flatness property is noted, the question amounts to the formation of $\omega_{X/R}$ commuting with base change on $R$ along the quotient map $R \rightarrow R/(t)$, but as you know, in the CM-morphism case it commutes with any base change at all.

Comment: You are making this too hard.  I mean $\omega_X$ not $\omega_{X/R}$ (although in Elkik's case, you can assume $R$ is a DVR if I recall correctly).  You don't need the flatness at all, $\omega_X$ is S2, so a regular element for $R$ acts as a regular element on $\omega_X$.  There is no need for any base change for canonical sheaves here.

Comment: @Karl Schwede: OK, not having the paper in front of me, I only saw what is in the question, where nothing is said about $R$ or what $\omega_X$ is supposed to mean, so I had to guess. If $R$ is CM but not Gorenstein then $\omega_X$ and $\omega_{X/R}$ are quite different things, so are you saying Elkik uses $\omega_X$ and not $\omega_{X/R}$? Also, $R$-flatness tells us that $t$ is regular on $X$, but the S2 condition merely concerns the existence of *some* sequence regular for the module, not that a specific element of the ring acts injectively.  Why does $t$ act injectively on $\omega_X$?

Comment: In Elkik's paper, all schemes are finite-type $\mathbb{C}$-schemes.  So $\omega_X$ makes perfect sense.  Elkik really wants to prove something about $\omega_X$ and not the relative term (although you can prove something along the line he wants with the relative term).  You are right though, without a little more information you can't know that $\omega_X$ even makes sense.  Let me respond to the other momentarily.

Comment: Since $X \to \text{Spec R}$ is flat, that fact that $t$ is a non-zero divisor on $R$ implies $t$ is a non-zero divisor on $X$.  Since it's a non-zero divisor on $X$ it is a non-zero divisor on $\omega_X$.  There isn't anything fancy to see this last statement, you can use the exact sequence I wrote in my answer.  Note that the first $\mathcal{H}om$ is still zero by dimension reasons.

Comment: Alternately, since $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, so is $\omega_X$, which has maximal support so regular elements on $X$ are regular on $\omega_X$.  $$.$$ In terms of the S2-ness, you are right, that wasn't clear.  One can easily show that $X$ is normal in Elkik's case.  Once you see that $X$ is normal, one can assume it is integral and $S2$ness (depending on your definition) implies torsion-freeness.